# Understanding the low-rank manifold

Tags: matrices, manifolds, matrix-rank, curvature

The manifold of (symmetric) rank-$k$-matrices is given by

$$M_n(k) = \left\{ X \in \mathbb R^{n\times n} : \mbox{rank} (X) = k \right\}$$

Why is the manifold of rank-$k$-matrices locally curved everywhere?

I am not familiar with formalizations of curvature, I would already be happy with some intuition.

---

**Note:** The tangent space at $X\in M_n(k)$ with singular value decomposition $X = U D U^\top$, where $U \in \mathbb R^{n\times k}$ and $D$ is diagonal, is given by

$$ T_{M_n(k)}X = \left\{ Y U^\top + U Y^\top : Y \in \mathbb R^{n \times k} \right\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out some intuition by myself:

For each rank-k-matrix $X$ there are other rank-$k$-matrices infinitesimally close with a slightly different tangent spaces since the row- respective columnspace has been perturbed (keep the form of the tangent space in mind).
Consider for example the following rank-2-matrices for small $\varepsilon>0$
$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \quad
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1+\varepsilon\\ 1 & 1+\varepsilon & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Since the tangent spaces changes locally there must be nonzero curvature.